# Primary maintainer gone. I was added to help maintain, but have no push access to the extension marketplace. What do I do?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I was recently added to a syntax theme repo to help maintain after the original maintainer has gone rogue.

The issue I'm having is that I'm unable to push to the extension marketplace. How would I go about getting access if I have no contact with the original maintainer?

Allow me to quickly answer what I'm sure will be the first question asked:

> "How were you added as a maintainer without contact to the original maintainer?"

The theme is a repository within a github organization containing repos across many different editors. The organization owner granted me contributor access, however he does not have push access to the vscode marketplace either.

Comment: Not sure if this is a good question for stackoverflow. Is it about programming?  Or should it be better asked on superuser or something.?

Comment: Was going to ask in the `vscode` repo itself, but their `issue_template.md` said to come here first.